Quines outside of academic environments?
For example this quine in Rust:
fn main(){let S="fn main(){let S={1}{0}{1};println!(S,S,'{1}')}";println!(S,S,'"')}

I have been playing around with quines lately and I am curious if there are any applications to real-world production environments? For example I've noticed that when asking a model like GPT questions, it will get fooled on quines, and get fooled on dynamic string interpolation in Rust (so the above quine I provided actually has a syntax error). But I don't know if it's necessarily a major bug that GPT would be fooled on something such as the original poster's quine, because I can't think of any situations where something like the above code would be used in a production environment.
Are there any production or real-world environments that quines such as the one I provided above would be used in (assuming the syntax gets corrected)?
